# Sitecore 10.3 JSS 21.0.1 Next.js - Unable to register fields for nested props in manifest definition

Tags: jss, nextjs

I am new to the Sitecore. I have created the Next.js application in disconnected mode.
I am trying to register below props in component definition file.

```
 fields: {
    NewsCards: {
      PreviewImage: ImageField;
      PreviewTitle: TextField;
      Author: {
        PreviewTitle: TextField;
        Position: TextField;
        Url: LinkField;
      };
      PublicationDate: DateField;
      UpdatedDate: DateField;
      PreviewCopy: RichTextField;
      Url: LinkField;
    }[];
  };
```

In sitecore/definitions/components file, trying to register fields like below:

```
  const author: FieldDefinition[] = [
    { name: 'PreviewTitle', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
    { name: 'Position', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
    { name: 'Url', type: CommonFieldTypes.GeneralLink },
  ] as FieldDefinition[];

  const NewCards: FieldDefinition [] = [
    
    { name: 'PreviewImage', type: CommonFieldTypes.Image },
    { name: 'PreviewTitle', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
    { name: 'PublicationDate', type: CommonFieldTypes.Date },
    { name: 'UpdatedDate', type: CommonFieldTypes.ItemLink },
    { name: 'PreviewCopy', type: CommonFieldTypes.RichText },
    { name: 'Url', type: CommonFieldTypes.GeneralLink },
    { name: 'Position', type: CommonFieldTypes.SingleLineText },
    { name: 'Url', type: CommonFieldTypes.GeneralLink },
     author 

  ] as FieldDefinition[];

  manifest.addComponent({
    name: 'Page3',
    icon: SitecoreIcon.DocumentTag,
    fields: NewCards as FieldDefinition[]
   
  });
```

It is not showing any error in the file. But when try to deploy the application, throwing below error.

```
[Error [ValidationError]: "fields[8]" must be of type object].
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the error is, but PSA:  Stop using disconnected mode, it doesn't work well. Code First should not be done with next.js, just use Sitecore first from the start. At some point you are going to have to move over to that anyway, it will save you time and pain.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Seems like you have duplicate field entry 'Url' in NewCards field definition. Try  removing it.

Comment: Thank you @VikrantPunwatkar for your suggestion! I corrected that, but still the issue persists. I have solved this problem with templates.